# binding collection change to view render

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

In spite of the many questions/answers on this same topic on StackOverflow and elsewhere, I still don't understand how to proceed. I would like a change in my collection to trigger the render function in my view. View has a collection, not a model -- so the many examples I see for model.bind are not applicable. Apparently collection.bind is not a legitimate binding. Here's my view code. What should I add in initialize so that when orderedPrefs (collection) has a change, the view's render function is called?

```
headerView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#' + targetdiv),
        collection: orderedPrefs,
        events: {
            "click .scheduleheader": "clicked"                               // dependency here on scheduler.js class naming .scheduleheader

        },
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, "render");

        },
        render: function () {
            alert('render!!');
        },
```

.....
.....

Answer (score 3):

These should work inside the initialize function:

```
this.collection.on("add", this.render);
this.collection.on("remove", this.render);
this.collection.on("reset", this.render);
```

If they don't, you have a problem with the collection attached to the view. You should not use global "orderedPrefs".

Backbone docs state:

*When creating a new View, the options you pass are attached to the view as this.options, for future reference. There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: model, collection, el, id, className, tagName and attributes.*

When instantiating your view, you need to pass the collection like this:

```
new headerView({ collection: orderedPrefs });
```

If you want to track changes in the collection models, you should do it in a different view:

```
var ModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.render();
        this.model.on("change",this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html("model view markup"); // you should use templating
        return this;
    }
});

var headerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#' + targetdiv),
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.collection.on("add", this.render);
        this.collection.on("remove", this.render);
        this.collection.on("reset", this.render);
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(collectionModel){
            var view = new ModelView({ model : collectionModel });
            $(self.el).append(view.el);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind using `collection.on` to the "add" and "remove" events.  See the [documentation under **Add**](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) for an example of usage.

```
this.collection.on("add", this.render);
```

If you're using Backbone version 0.9.0 or newer, then you can bind multiple events in the same statement:

```
this.collection.on("add remove", this.render);
```

Note also that "bind" should work the same as "on":

> bind and unbind have been renamed to on and off for clarity, following jQuery's lead. The old names are also still supported.

Comment: But what about when my collection is already loaded and I made mods to underlying models - looks as though I have no means of binding to a change in such a case? Looks as though I would need to bind to underlying model to catch a change (as in, edit)?

Comment: @goldfinger No, you can use the "change" event to be notified of a change to any model in the collection.  Just going from the docs here -- the wording is a bit ambiguous, so I'm not 100% sure:  *You can bind "change" events to be notified when any model in the collection has been modified*

Comment: Something remains wrong that I simply can't understand.  this.collection.bind("change", this.render) gives 'object doesn't support property or method bind' error in JavaScript, which is why in OP I mentioned collection.bind doesn't seem to be a legitimate binding. I'm not sure what's wrong on my end....

Comment: @goldfinger the `Collection` object definitely supports `bind` -- so maybe the collection isn't getting set correctly.  Where is `orderedPrefs` defined in your example?